# How to get last log entries with specific ids

Tags: sqlite

I am logging temperatures for several sensors in an sqlite db. Each sensor has a unique id which are in a table which has the ids and names for the sensors. The log file has a table with dates, id, temp. I would like a query which lists the last(most recent) log entry for each id.

Comment: If you mean the sensor table has a foreign key on log table and you want to list the most recent log for each sensors, then you can select logs by their dates or you can add a independent id for log table you just need to select max id from log where the sensor_id (foreign key) is equal to what id you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

select max(rowid),sensorid, date, temp from table group by sensorid